# NoSuchMethodError error when invoking projectListRequest.execute() method

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to develop a simple BigQuery App using JSP Servlets. I am following the exampla given on https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization

In the early stages, the doGet method was not getting invoked and so I overrided the Service method. The code looks like this

```
public class BigQueryWebServerAuthDemo extends AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet {

 protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws IOException, ServletException {
     System.out.println(" Start service ");
     doGet(req, resp);
 }

  @Override

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws IOException {

   System.out.println(" Start doGet ");

   doPost(request, response);
     }

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {
  System.out.println(" Start doPost "); 

response.setContentType("text/html");

PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

System.out.println(" Begin loadbigquery() ");

Bigquery bigquery = CredentialUtils.loadbigquery();

System.out.println(" end loadbigquery() ");

Bigquery.Projects.List projectListRequest = bigquery.projects().list();
ProjectList projectList = projectListRequest.execute();

if (projectList.getProjects() != null) {

  java.util.List<Projects> projects = projectList.getProjects();
  writer.println("<h3>BigQuery project list:</h3>");

  for (ProjectList.Projects project : projects) {
    writer.printf("%s<br />", project.getProjectReference().getProjectId());
  }

}
System.out.println(" End doPost "); 
 }

      @Override
     protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(" inside BigQueryWebServerAuthDemo ---  initializeFlow() "); 

     return CredentialUtils.newFlow();
    }

   @Override
  protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(" inside BigQueryWebServerAuthDemo --- getRedirectUri() "); 

   return CredentialUtils.getRedirectUri(request);
   }

   @Override
   protected String getUserId(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException,               IOException {

    System.out.println(" inside BigQueryWebServerAuthDemo --- getUserId "); 

       return request.getParameter("userId");  
      }
```

}

I have a JSP page from where I am getting the parameter "userId". Now I get a
NoSuchMethodError on execute() method [projectListRequest.execute()] though Eclipse compiler doesnt show any error.

Below is my web.xml config info

```
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>oauth2callback</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>main.BigQueryWebServerAuthCallBack</servlet-class>
     </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>oauth2callback</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/oauth2callback</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>ServletBigQuery</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>main.BigQueryWebServerAuthDemo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ServletBigQuery</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/ServletBigQuery</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have 2 more classes CredentialUtils and BigQueryWebServerAuthCallBack as given in the tutorial mentioned above.

I am actually new to Java . I want get rid of the NoSuchMethodError error. Any help         will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: resolved this issue after a lot of googling. there were few unnecessary jars in project build path.once i removed them ...it was a smooth ride